# Android Studio + NDK - Import Existing C++

Tags: android, c++, android-studio, android-ndk, java-native-interface

How can I both **include in the compilation** and **view in the project file tree** some `.h` and `.cpp` files **located outside of the project directory** ?

With Visual Studio and a C++ project you would simply use "Add existing item", select your files and voilà, it just works in ten seconds. Aren't Android-based development supposed to make developper's lives easier ? :/

I've been searching for hours how to do this now. None of the answers I found is addressing this.

I can't beleive that, among all the people who have been using Android Studio with the NDK, none of them have used C++ code outside of the `jni` folder...

Do you know how to do ? Thank you.

Comment: using ndk is always painful until now..

Comment: Do you know a way to include a separate file INSIDE of jni folder? http://stackoverflow.com/q/32818293/753575

Answer (score 4):

Here's what I've done. First install newest Android Studio 1.4 released today (but I worked on first 1.3 preview with ndk support).
To have NDK support you'll need to switch to **Gradle 2.5** (Project Structure -> Project -> Gradle Version). Use **experimental gradle-plugin** (in main build.gradle "classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle-experimental:0.2.0'").

Then you need to **update your apps build.gradle** file to new format as explained here: http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/gradle-experimental

My project consisted of a static lib and dynamic lib. Unfortunately this is not supported and you must compile it as one dynamic lib for now. Custom makefiles are not supported.

This is the tricky part, you need to put it inside model { }

```
android.ndk {
    moduleName = "NativeLib"

    // toolchain = "clang" <- tried using it, but failed
    // toolchainVersion = "3.5"

    stl = "gnustl_static" // you can switch stl lib this way

    ldLibs += "log"
    cppFlags += "-g"
    cppFlags += "-std=c++11" // use c++11
    cppFlags += "-Wall"
    cppFlags += "-I${file("../../../common/include")}".toString() // include folder
}

android.sources {
    main {
        jni {
            source {
                srcDirs = ['src/main/jni', '../../../common']
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You can change the paths if your native source files reside elsewhere - this is from my project structure.