# How to add a single file to paths in Android studio 1.3+ with experimental gradle plugin (NDK)?

Tags: android-studio, android-ndk, gradle-plugin

There are a lot of examples with adding a whole source folder to paths like a

```
cppFlags += "-I${file("src/main/jni/native_app_glue")}".toString()
```

in new experimental gradle plugin for AS 1.3+

Is there a way to add single source file to it?

Answer (score 0):

The snippet you're showing is adding an include directory, not sources. It will add headers, not .c/.cpp files.

I haven't found a way to add a single source.

The plugin will look for all the sources inside jni folders.
You can add a jni folder using *jni.source.srcDirs*:

```
android.sources{
    main.jni {
        source {
            srcDirs += "src/main/other_jni_sources"
        }
    }
}
```